# Cannot run matplotlib with Apache Zeppelin

Tags: python, matplotlib, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin and matplotlib to visualize some data. I try them but fail with the error below. Could you give me some guidance how to fix it?

```
%pyspark
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

And here is the error I've got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-3580576524078731606.py", line 235, in <module>
    eval(compiledCode)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 78, in <module>
    new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gtk; gdk = gtk.gdk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
```

I also try to add these lines, but still cannot work

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Answer (score 8):

The following works for me with Spark & Python 3:

```
%pyspark

import matplotlib
import io

# If you use the use() function, this must be done before importing matplotlib.pyplot. Calling use() after pyplot has been imported will have no effect.
# see: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show(p):
    img = io.StringIO()
    p.savefig(img, format='svg')
    img.seek(0)
    print("%html <div style='width:600px'>" + img.getvalue() + "</div>")

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
show(plt)
```

The Zeppelin [documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/interpreter/python.html#matplotlib-integration) suggests that the following should work:

```
%python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
(.. ..)
z.show(plt)
plt.close()
```

This doesn't work for me with Python 3, but looks to be addressed with the soon-to-be-merged [PR #1213](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/1213).

Comment: It works with Python2.7 on ubuntu. After `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`

Comment: Thank you guys, I know what happens with my cluster, it's because I use python 2.6. All I need to do is upgrade my python to 2.7

Answer (score 4):

Note that as of Zeppelin 0.7.3, matplotlib integration is much more seamless, so the methods described here are no longer necessary. https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/python.html#matplotlib-integration

Comment: yes, also see http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/spark.html

Answer (score 1):

As per @eddies suggestion, I tried and this is what worked for me on Zeppelin 0.6.1 python 2.7

```
%python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
z.show(plt, width='500px')
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
plt.switch_backend('agg')
```

Complete code example Spark 2.2.0 + python3(anaconda3.5):

```
%spark.pyspark

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
plt.switch_backend('agg')
import numpy as np
import io

def show(p):
    img = io.StringIO()
    p.savefig(img, format='svg')
    img.seek(0)
    print ("%html <div style='width:600px'>" + img.getvalue() + "</div>")

# Example data
people=('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos=np.arange(len(people))
performance=3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error=np.random.rand(len(people))

plt.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.yticks(y_pos, people)
plt.xlabel('Performance')
plt.title('How fast do you want to go today?')

show(plt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use IPython/IPySpark interpreter in zeppelin 0.8.0 which will be released soon. The matplotlib integration in ipython is almost the same as jupyter. There's one tutorial https://www.zepl.com/viewer/notebooks/bm90ZTovL3pqZmZkdS9lN2Q3ODNiODRkNjA0ZjVjODM1OWZlMWExZjM4OTk3Zi9ub3RlLmpzb24